# Production vs QA configuration

Tags: configuration

Time and again I am faced with the issue of having multiple environments that must be configured individually for an application that would run in all of them (e.g. QA, regional production env's, dev, staging, etc.) and I am wondering what would be the best way to organize different configurations?

Would it be in the database? Different configuration files per environment? Or maybe the same file with different sections/xml tags? How would these be then deployed? Embedded within the app? Or put manually in after installation to be modified in-place?

This question is not technology-specific - I've worked with .net and Java, web-apps and desktop apps and this issue comes up time and again. I'm looking to learn different approaches to maybe adapt a hybrid to address this.

EDIT: There's one caveat that I must point out - when configuration is part of the deployed solution, it is generally installed under `root` user on the host. In large organizations developers usually don't have a root access to production hosts so any changes to the configuration require a new build and deployment. Needless to say this isn't the nicest approach - especially at organizations that have a very strict release process involving multiple teams and approval levels... (*sigh* I know!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowed from Jez Humble and David Farley's book "[Continuous Delivery (page 41)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912)", you can:

> - Your build scripts can pull configuration in and incorporate it into your binaries at **build** time.
> - Your packaging software can inject configuration at **packaging** time, such as when creating assemblies, ears, or gems.
> - Your deployment scripts or installers can fetch the necessary information or ask the user for it and pass it to your application at
>     deployment time as part of the **installation process**.
> - Your application itself can fetch configuration at **startup time** or **run time**.

It is considered bad practice by them to inject configuration files in build and compile times, because you should be able to deploy the same binary file to every environments.

My experience was that you could bake all configuration files for every environments (except sensitive information) to your deployment file (war, jar, zip, etc). And you design your application to take in an extra parameter when starts, to pickup the right sets of configuration files (from your extracted deployment file, or from local/remote file system if they are sensitive, or from a database) during application's startup time.

Comment: This makes sense! I think application/env specific configs should be picked at installation/deployment time and user-specific configs should be applied at startup/access time.

Answer (score 1):

The question is difficult to answer because it's somewhat vague. There is no technology-agnostic approach to configuration as far as I know. Exactly how configuration is set up will depend on the language/technology in question.

I'm not familiar with .net but with java a popular approach is to have a [maven build set up with different profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html). Each profile is specific to an environment. You can then define different properties files that have environment-specific values, an example from the above link is:

> - environment.properties - This is the default configuration and will be packaged in the artifact by default.
> - environment.test.properties - This is the variant for the test environment.
> - environment.prod.properties - This is basically the same as the test variant and will be used in the production environment.

You can then build your project as follows:

```
mvn -Pprod package
```

Comment: In Asp.net applications you can setup partial configuration files to correspond to build type (Debug vs Release). The system will then pick the right portion of configs to put together a proper configuration/properties file, similar to your maven example.

Answer (score 0):

I have good news and bad news.

The good news is that Config4* (of which I am the maintainer) neatly addresses this issue with its support for *adaptive configuration*. Basically, this is the ability for a configuration file to adapt itself to the environment (including hostname, username, environment variables, and command-line options) in which it is running. Read [Chapter 2](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/overview-of-config4star-syntax.html) of the "Getting Started" manual for details. Don't worry: it is a short chapter.

The bad news is that, currently, Config4* implementations exist only for C++ and Java, so your .Net applications are out of luck. And even with C++ and Java applications, it won't make pragmatic sense to retrofit Config4* into an existing application. Because of this, I'd advise trying to use Config4* only in *new* applications.

Despite the bad news, I think it is worth your while to read the above-mentioned chapter of the Config4* documentation, because doing so may provide you with ideas that you can adapt to fit your needs.